# How to prove that $E(Y|D=1)=E(DY)/E(D)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, conditional-expectation

How to prove that
$$E(Y|D=1)=E(DY)/E(D)$$
and
$$E(Y|X,D=1)=E(DY|X)/E(D|X),$$
where $D$ is a binary variable and takes value of 0 and 1.

Comment: Have you tried Bayes' Theorem? That's the first thing that pops to mind

Comment: This is not true, in general. Say, $Y=D$, $E(D|D=1)=1$, and the r.h.s. $E(D^2)/E(D)$ need not to be $1$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Sorry, I forgot to give the definition of $D$. $D$ is a binary variable which takes value of 0 and 1. So $D^2=D$, then $E(D^2)/E(D)=E(D)/E(D)=1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First observe that $$\mathbb E[D]=1\cdot P(D=1)+0\cdot P(D=0)=P(D=1)\tag{1}$$ 
So, \begin{align}\mathbb E[YD]&=\mathbb E[Y\cdot 1\mid D=1]P(D=1)+\mathbb E[Y\cdot 0\mid D=0]P(D=0)\\&\overset{(1)}=\mathbb E[Y\mid D=1]\mathbb E[D]+0\end{align} and the result follows by rearranging terms and assuming that $P(D=1)>0$. Can you do the same for the $X$ part?

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind help. Following your solution, I prove the conditional case as below.

Answer (score 1):

The unconditional case is shown as above. For the conditional case, first observe that 
$$\mathbb E[D|X]=1\cdot P(D=1|X)+0\cdot P(D=0|X)=P(D=1|X)\tag{1}$$ 
So, 
\begin{align}\mathbb E[YD|X]&=\mathbb E[YD|X,D=1]\cdot P(D=1|X)+\mathbb E[YD|X,D=0]\cdot P(D=0|X)\\&\overset{(1)}=\mathbb E[Y| X, D=1]\cdot\mathbb E[D|X]\end{align} 
and the conditional equation follows by rearranging terms and assuming that $P(D=1|X)\neq0$.